# ¿Por qué al intentar sumar dos variables de tipo byte/short y asignar el resultado al mismo tipo el compilador Java muestra un error?

Tags: java

Por ejemplo, si tengo:

```
short a,b,c;
a=1;
b=2;
c=a+b;
```

Me aparece el error:

> error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from int to short

Comprendo que se puede arreglar ese error convirtiendo la operación para hacer el ajuste:

```
c=(short)(a+b);
```

O también se puede cambiar el tipo de `c` de `short` a `int`.

Pero ahora tengo la duda de porqué esto sucede solo con los tipos `byte` y `short` y no con otros tipos de datos de mayor tamaño como `int`.

Nota: intenté hacer la prueba con dos variables de tipo `int`, guardando en cada una la cantidad límite de este tipo de dato:

```
int d = 2147483647;
int e = 2147483647;
```

Al intentar sumarlas y guardar el resultado en una variable `f` de tipo `long` el resultado del programa siempre es un desbordamiento, no se aplica la misma regla que en el caso de los `short`:

```
long f=d+e;
System.out.println("valor de f: "+f);
```

La salida es:

> valor de f: -2.0

Comment: De momento no sé como responder a tu pregunta ya que tienes la solución que es castear, te sugiero revisar el tema de [literales numéricas](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) para que pongas cosas como `float d = 2147483647f;` y hasta donde sé, para short no hay una letra para definir una literal numérica.

Comment: Tienes que utilizar el `cast` por que    `short` hay de tipo `byte`,`int`, `float`, `double` y debes de especificar con que tipo de destino estas trabajando.

Comment: Aunque aparentemente parece que pudieran tener relación ambas preguntas, cada una de ellas tiene una explicación diferente. Hubiera sido interesante haberlas preguntado por separado. Espero que mi explicación te haya sido de utilidad.

Comment: Sí, muchas gracias por aclarar mi duda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema con el que te enfrentas es que Java implementa [suma de valores `int`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.2) pero no suma de valores `short`.

Para resolver la situación Java intenta convertir los tipos primitivos `short` a otro de mayor amplitud (mayor capacidad o número de bits) para resolver la operación aritmética, el tipo `int`, haciendo uso de la [*conversión a primitivas más amplias (Widening Primitive Conversion)*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2).

Es lógico pensar que se producirá una excepción por desbordamiento si sumas dos `int`, cuyo resultado es un `int`, pero quieres almacenarlo en un `short`.

Java te está avisando que podría producirse desbordamiento y que eso conllevaría a un problema en el funcionamiento en tu programa. Si estás de acuerdo con esa pérdida entonces debes hacer la conversión explícita del resultado a `short`:

```
c = (short)(a + b);
```

---

En la segunda parte de tu pregunta se produce una suma de enteros, por lo que no requiere del uso de ampliación del tipo. Al sumar enteros el resultado no es que desborde el tipo, si no que de manera cíclica el siguiente número después del `2147483647` (`01111111 11111111 11111111 11111111`) es el `-2147483648` (`10000000 00000000 00000000 00000000`) debido a cómo funcionan los números en complemento a dos.

Para ver este comportamiento te presento esta prueba de concepto:

```
int n = 2147483646;
for (int cuenta = 0; cuenta < 4; cuenta++, n++) {
  System.out.println("Nº" + cuenta + ": " + n);
}
```

El resultado de la prueba de concepto es:

```
Nº0: 2147483646
Nº1: 2147483647
Nº2: -2147483648
Nº3: -2147483647
```

En tu pregunta estás sumando valores positivos cuyo resultado en el tipo de dato `int` se convierte en un valor negativo debido a que se activa el bit de signo:

```
System.out.println("Suma  (d + 1): " + (int)(d + 1L));
System.out.println("Suma f(d + 1): " + (float)(d + 1));
System.out.println("Suma  (d + e): " + (d + e));
System.out.println("Suma f(d + e): " + (float)(d + e));
System.out.println("Suma  (L + L): " + (2147483647L + 2147483647L));
System.out.println("Suma f(L + L): " + (float)(2147483647L + 2147483647L));
```

Resultado:

```
Suma  (d + 1): -2147483648
Suma f(d + 1): -2.14748365E9
Suma  (d + e): -2
Suma f(d + e): -2.0
Suma  (L + L): 4294967294
Suma f(L + L): 4.2949673E9
```

En el primer caso el siguiente número, como hemos dicho, es negativo porque el que sigue a `2147483647` es el `-2147483648`.

En el tercer caso se obtiene `-2` porque el resultado de la suma es:

```
  01111111 11111111 11111111 11111111
+ 01111111 11111111 11111111 11111111
--------------------------------------
  11111111 11111111 11111111 11111110
```

Ese resultado en un tipo `long` (o en un tipo `unsigned int` de C, que no existe en Java) valdría `4294967294` (como se muestra en el quinto caso), pero en un `int` (teniendo en cuenta que usa complemento a dos) ese valor representa al número `-2`.

Comment: Quiero añadir a la respuesta una notas que encontré que dicen lo siguiente: cuando se realizan operaciones como la suma y los dos operandos son de tipo primitivo, el tipo de dato resultante es determinado por el operando de tipo más grande, por lo que en algunos casos podrían presentarse problemas de sobreflujo. Por lo tanto el programador debe considerar si el tipo de variables que utilizará son los suficientemente grandes para contener los datos y evitar ese problema.

Comment: Eres libre de, y se agradece, agregar lo que desees a mi respuesta @MED_M . Si proporcionas los enlaces necesarios a la fuente de las referencias que hagas será un placer validar tu edición.